# failed to upload distribution using fastlane

Tags: fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I am using Fastlane to build Android builds. With Fastlane, I am using firebase_app_distribution plugin to distribute the .apk to testers. We have implemented an ACL on outbound so only whitelisted IP Addresses are allowed.

I got the error message on a continuous basis after every two days **Error: failed to upload distribution. Server Error. connect ECONNREFUSED x.x.x.x:443**

After whitelisting the IP Address, firebase_app_distribution plugin able to upload and distribute the .apk to testers. IP Address is changing on a regular basis so I have to whitelist the new IP address to work firebase_app_distribution plugin.

Can someone share the DNS name so I will add DNS and Ip Addresses behind that DNS got updated automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com
appdistribution-uploads.crashlytics.com
```